# Tab-swipe animation on ion-tabs in Ionic 2/Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I've gone through Tabs swipe using Ionic 1 in the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35046901/ionic-sliding-between-tabs-template). I want to do the similar thing with Ionic 2 app. Kindly assist me how to do that. I've posted my tabs.html and tabs.ts below

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
 
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-tabs',
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html',
})
export class TabsPage {
 
  tab1Root: any = 'Tab1Page';
  tab2Root: any = 'Tab2Page';
  tab3Root: any = 'Tab3Page';
  tab4Root: any = 'Tab4Page';
  myIndex: number;
 
  constructor(navParams: NavParams) {
    // Set the active tab based on the passed index from menu.ts
    this.myIndex = navParams.data.tabIndex || 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<ion-tabs [selectedIndex]="myIndex">
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Tab1" tabIcon="albums"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Tab2" tabIcon="people"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Tab3" tabIcon="podium"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="Tab4" tabIcon="pricetags"></ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: Using super-tabs is the only way or we can achieve it with any directives for ion-tabs itself?

Comment: On your prescribed example, I'm getting this following error. Kindly assist

Comment: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'root' since it isn't a known property of 'super-tab'. 1. If 'super-tab' is an Angular component and it has 'root' input, then verify that it is part of this module. 2. If 'super-tab' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. 3. To allow any property add .............